# Android: Rerun Database onCreate() if it fails

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, android-database

Because of some poor decisions, I am stuck with an `onCreate()` in my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class that can run for up to 5 minutes. The user could turn off his phone, or force close the app during this process, meaning my onCreate() will be canceled prematurely. If that is the case - I need the database to be wiped and `onCreate()` rerun. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you doing that makes it take up to 5 minutes? are you initializing data as well?

Comment: initializing a database based on the files in the assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your tables in `onCreate()` and initialise the data in another `Service` or background thread.

In that background thread, call `beginTransaction()` on your `SQLiteDatabase` object before you initialise the data. Then call `setTransactionSuccessful()` and `endTransaction()` when it has finished.
Keep a flag in `SharedPreferences` so you can check if this initialisation has already happened or not

Answer (score 0):

You should use a transaction. If you finalize it (when the process is complete), all the data will be written onto the database.
Otherwise, they won't.

If you don't know what a transaction is, here is a tutorial on transactions: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_transactions.htm

In few words, a transaction allows you to write all data in a burst; if there is no finalization to a begun transaction, the data won't be written.

So, if any error occurs or your user forces a close, the transaction won't be finalized and no data will be written.